# Which part of the sentence does "for you" modify?

Tags: prepositions

> I have some free advice ***for you***.

Does "for you" modify "some free advice "? Or it modifies "I have some free advice" ? Which one is correct? Is "for you " a post-positioned  modifier or a sentence adverbial?

Answer (score 2):

An interesting sentence.

Syntactically, *for you* might be understood either

- as an adjunct modifying *free advice* (‘I have free advice which is intended for you’), or
- as a complement of the adjective *free* (‘I have advice which is free for you’).

To my mind, however, semantics trumps syntax here. The clear **meaning** of the sentence is an announcement of impending action: ‘I am going to give you some free advice’. In that context, *for you* is a preposition phrase expressing the Indirect Object of the action.

This can be justified syntactically (if you need to justify it) by understanding *have advice* in a benefactive rather than a possessive sense.